# Stop VSCode changing line breaks

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do you stop VS Code from automatically removing line breaks on save?

For example, it turns:

```
      return MaterialApp(
        routes: appRoutes,
        theme: appTheme
      );
```

Into:

```
return MaterialApp(routes: appRoutes, theme: appTheme);
```

Which I find pretty disorienting at times.

Answer (score 0):

You might have installed some extensions formatting this language.

You can set

```
"editor.formatOnSave": false
```

in VSCode settings.

Or

```
"[html]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false
},
```

for specific language.